# Youtube and Facebook Video opening in media player when clicking button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube, uibutton, media-player

I am noob with iPhone programming. I want to ask question regarding the Video and Facebook link.

I create list of page and when user clicks page, the view will show description of video and a button to play the video.

1.Is it possible to play facebook and youtube video in media player when user clicks Button?

because each page has different video, and i only get embedded link of a youtube video (not video file format and the video identifier).

2.How to send parameter to IBAction? Because when user click button it depends on the video link on selected page.

What my apps look like will be similar with SBS News Australia apps in section part where user can click play button and go to media player.

Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you can't play YouTube (or Facebook) videos with MPMoviePlayerController. You can open and play a YouTube video with UIWebView, but you can't play any other flash video (like Facebook videos).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. So facebook video cannot be played in iPhone right ? (due to flash video). 
If cannot be played in media player, can the youtube embed link be played in Youtube app?
What i want is when user click play button the Video is loaded in full screen (whether by mediaplayer or other app).

Comment: Just open the page in an UIwebView, and set the allowsInlineMediaPlayback to no. This way it should work as you described.

Comment: Okay, but i have another problem. I do not want to show my uiwebview to the screen. If i use this method, user need click Play button in uiwebview. What i want is: when i clicks my button it will go directly to "media player" like when clicking play button in uiwebview.  Is it possible?

Comment: you can play youtube videos with MPMoviePlayerController but firstly you should parse youtube html and get video url from it.